# Icinga2 node wizard does not set address

Tags: linux, monitoring

We have successfully installed Icinga2 on a master server and on several client nodes. We used the new `icinga2 node wizard` to setup first the master and then the nodes.

After the process is completed, we receive SQL errors in icingaweb that `inet` is not set.

By checking, we saw that in the automatically created `myhost.conf` in `repository.d/` there is no address attribute in there.

By manually adding the IP address as an attribute and reloading, the SQL error disappears.

Does anybody know what we did wrong or if this is by design?

We followed the step by step setup here:

http://docs.icinga.org/icinga2/latest/doc/module/icinga2/chapter/monitoring-remote-systems#icinga2-remote-client-monitoring

Here is the `.conf` file that was produce by running the `node wizard` on a remote host

```
object Host "myhost.org" {
        import "satellite-host"
        check_command = "cluster-zone"
}
```